# How to test a function from a svelte component with jest?

Tags: jestjs, svelte, ts-jest, babel-jest

There is a lot of documentation on the internet to test svelte component with jest, calling render functions and simulating browser events. This is nice, but how can I test a function inside a svelte component?

#### mycompoment.svelte

```
<script>
function veryComplicated(foo) {
     ...
}
</script>

<div>...</div>
```

#### mycomponent.test.js

```
import { veryComplicated } from "./mycomponent.svelte"

test('it works', async () => {
    expect(vercomplicated("foo").toBe("bar"))
})
```

#### jest

```
 FAIL  src/mycomponent.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    src/mycomponent.test.ts:1:10 - error TS2614: Module '"*.svelte"' has no exported member 'veryComplicated'. Did you mean to use 'import veryComplicated from "*.svelte"' instead?

    1 import { veryComplicated } from "./mycomponent.svelte"
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.697 s
Ran all test suites.
```

Adding `export` before the `veryComplicated` definition does not help.

How can I test the `veryComplicated` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it. I had to call `render`.

#### mycomponent.test.js

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/svelte'
import MyComponent from "./mycomponent.svelte"

test('it works', async () => {
    const component = render(MyComponent)
    expect(component.veryComplicated("foo")).toBe("bar")
})
```

And it is needed to export the `veryComplicated` function in the original file:

```html
<script>
export function veryComplicated(foo) {
     ...
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can export a function using a module context script block.

```
<script context="module">
    export veryComplicated() {
        // ...
    }
</script>

<div>...</div>
```

Then you can do `import { veryComplicated } from './mycomponent.svelte'` as you were originally trying to do.

https://svelte.dev/tutorial/module-exports